# In c, do the macros __FILE__, __LINE__ & __PRETTY_FUNCTION__ allocate memory?

Tags: c, multithreading, pointers, memory, macros

Lets assume the following code:

`char* c = __FILE__;`

Does c exist on the stack or the heap? (and as a follow up - Can I pass c to another thread for handling or do I need to memcpy the data someplace else?).

Thank you.

Answer (score 5):

`c` is a variable of pointer type and exists wherever (with whatever storage duration) it's declared with based on the scope where your declaration lies. It's initialized with the address of a string literal, which has static storage duration, is not modifiable, and may be collapsed with identical strings.

If you change it to `__PRETTY_FUNCTION__`, it's unlike the others you asked about because it's not a macro the preprocessor can expand. The preprocessor fundamentally cannot have any idea about function boundaries (what if the function were actually being defined piecewise by macros the preprocessor is expanding?) so it's a special extension that's essentially an implicitly-declared static local variable of array type initialized with a string containing the pretty function name.

Comment: It's a `static` array with local scope. So it's address is persistent.

Answer (score 2):

`__FILE__` is a macro, which expands to a string literal, like `"foo.c"`.

String literals are stored in some global storage (which is neither stack nor heap). They exist as long as the program is running, so you can pass pointers to them to other threads safely.

`__LINE__` is a macro which expands to a number, like `42`. Since it's just an `int`, you can safely copy it around.

`__PRETTY_FUNCTION__` is a static variable (`const char` array), implicitly created at function scope. It also exists as long as the program is running.

Answer (score 0):

Macros are processed by the pre-processor. So what will probably happen is that:

```
char* c = __FILE__;
```

Will be changed to this by the preprocessor:

```
char* c = "ThisIsMyFilename.c";
```

Note that the pointer value is guaranteed to point to that constant forever so you can copy the pointer value or pass it to another thread without issue. Of course, do not attempt to modify its contents!

Comment: Thank you for your response David.

My understanding is that (in your example) "ThisIsMyFilename.c" resides in some place (read only) in memory, and as long as I have the address of that memory location I can access the data, so there is no need for copying.

I want to verify that I understand correctly (or in case I don't - how does this actually work).

Answer (score 0):

`__FILE__` expands to a string literal, and as all string literals it need to be stored in the executable. It stored as an array of (read-only) characters (including null-terminator). So in a way the compiler "allocate" memory for it.

The (non-standard) symbol `__PRETTY_FUNCTION__` is a special local variable which is an array of characters, which takes up space similar to other arrays and string literals.

The `__LINE__` macro expands to an integer literal, which doesn't typically take up space by themselves.

And of course the variable itself needs some space.

Comment: `__PRETTY_FUNCTION__` does not and fundamentally cannot expand to a string literal. It's an implicitly declared local variable of array type, initialized with the name.